# Use wp init hook to call other hooks?

Tags: hooks, customization, init, admin-init

I want to know if it is a good practice according to WordPress theme or plugin development.

```
add_action('init','all_my_hooks');

function all_my_hooks(){

// some initialization stuff here and then

add_action('admin_init',-----);
add_action('admin_menu',----);

// more like so

}
```

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In general: Yes, wait for a dedicated hook to start your own code. [Never](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57079/how-to-remove-a-filter-that-is-an-anonymous-object/57088#57088) just throw an object instance into the global namespace. But `init` is rarely necessary.

You hook in as late as possible. If your first code runs on `wp_head` do not use an earlier hook. You can even [cascade hooks](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/46135/how-to-var-dump-nav-menu-items-from-anywhere/46262#46262):

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'first_callback' );

function first_callback()
{
    // do something
    // then
    add_action( 'wp_footer', 'second_callback' );
}
```

Regarding the `init` hook: Use `wp_loaded` instead. That runs after `init` and after  `ms_site_check()` was called. This way you avoid to run your plugin on an invalid sub site in a multi-site installation. Everything else is the same.

Comment: +1 for `wp_loaded` and MS info.

Comment: thanks a lot for your response, still a doubt, which is better load all other hooks inside wp_loaded or load them separately ? i wonder if i add hooks in wp_loaded they will be hooked earlier instead of getting hooked after admin_init or admin_menu ?

Comment: cascading hooks isn't an issue ?

Comment: No, why should it be? Call the second hook only if the first was useful.

Answer (score 5):

I don't see the **big** benefits of this practice, for these reasons:

### Your callback functions aren't called when registering

The `add_action` and `add_filter` functions only add an entry to global variable `$wp_filter` which holds all filters and actions. [See source](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/plugin.php#L65). It doesn't call your function. Your code will run *only* when the `do_action` and `apply_filters` are called (with appropriate hook name), which happens *very late* in the place where those hooks should be.

You might say that doing so will make the global variable `$wp_filter` getting bigger => more memory required. But I think creating a new function has the same problem.

### Organizing code

Putting everything in *one* function force you to remember all hooks in every files in your theme/plugin. You **wouldn't** do something like this:

- in `header.php`: add hooks and callback functions for things happen in header (like menu, registering script)
- in `content.php`: add hooks and callback functions for filtering content
- `admin-menu.php`: add hooks and callback functions to add admin menu

(assume that those files are put in your theme/plugin)

Instead of that, you have to:

- put only callback functions in `header.php`, `content.php`, `admin-menu.php`
- and put all hooks in a separated function in another file

=> That will make you hard to know what happens when you look at the content of `header.php` file. You have to search to know when these callbacks are fired.

And think about situation when you have multiple classes in your theme/plugin. Do you put all hooks of all classes in one place? Or does each class has a wrapper function that holds all hooks? It's too redundant!

Above these reason, I think it's personal style :). I see some frameworks like Hybrid does what you said. Sometimes it makes me hard to digg in those frameworks!