# Failed to invoke other hook from the init hook

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, filters, hooks, customization

Related to this question ([Use wp init hook to call other hooks?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/67634/use-wp-init-hook-to-call-other-hooks)) but not the same.

Sometimes, I found that the hook will failed to run when I place inside the init hook, e.g.

Not Work:

```
add_action('init','my_init');
function my_init() {
    add_filter('locale', ...
}
```

Work:

```
add_action('init','my_init');
add_filter('locale', ...
```

Of course some hooks/filters will just work okay inside the init hook, but **definitely not all of them.**

So it seems to me that **it is a bad practice to chain actions/filters together?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `locale` hook happens long before `init`. To see when which hook, variable, constant, function, class or file is available install my plugin [T5 WP Load Order](https://gist.github.com/4055044).

You get a looong file with a very detailed log. Search for `Hook: locale`, then for `Hook: init`. You will see that you need `plugins_loaded` as parent action if you want to chain hooks.

Is it a good practice? It depends. If you need the second callback only when the first was running successful, then **yes**. If both callbacks should run independently of each other, then **no**.
Chaining should reflect the logic of your program.

Comment: Thanks, will definitely check out your plugin to have a look. The reason I ask is the `init` hook of your plugin must success anyway if the plugin is activated, so chaining inside the `init` just delay the execution and caused the troublesome in dependency.

Comment: That plugin looks great, thanks for sharing it. Another awesome one is the WordPress Hook Sniffer - http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-hook-sniffer/

Answer (score 2):

Attaching to a hook inside of a callback of another hook is not a bad practice, contrary, sometimes it's mandatory. The problem is that you should be aware of the sequence of actions and filters, as you could try to invoke an action while you're executing something else after the first action (so your second hook is already executed and it's too late for newly attached events).

Comment: Hi, as the dependency stuff of action/filter is fragile and error prone, I am thinking - always register earlier and let your callback to decide if it should be executed seems to be a better approach

Comment: Quite true, though it's not always possible to register at earlier point due to the fact that data-sensitive variables are used (like post, or whatever), also you could mess up the future flow if your logic is branched.