# Proper after_setup_theme and wp_head cleanup

Tags: filters, actions, wp-head, customization

Im trying to clean up code in my theme a little bit, remove some of the code that is not used and basically do things the right way, to decrease load time etc.

Currently I have this code:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'rm_theme_setup');

// start theme setup
function rm_theme_setup() {
    add_action('init', 'rm_head_cleanup'); // * 1) calling the function below
    add_action('wp_head', 'rm_remove_recent_comments_style', 1);
    add_filter('gallery_style', 'rm_remove_gallery_style');

    rm_add_theme_support(); // * 2) calling the function to add theme support
}
```

**1) This is the wp_head cleanup part:** Basically Im calling this function in the theme_setup function above. Is this the correct way to do things?

```
function rm_head_cleanup() {
    remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links_extra', 3);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'feed_links', 2);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'rsd_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wlwmanifest_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'index_rel_link');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'parent_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'start_post_rel_link', 10, 0);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'adjacent_posts_rel_link_wp_head', 10, 0);
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_generator');
    remove_action('wp_head', 'wp_shortlink_wp_head');
    add_filter('style_loader_src', 'rm_remove_wp_ver_css_js');
    add_filter('style_loader_tag', 'rm_clean_style_tags');
    add_filter('script_loader_src', 'rm_remove_wp_ver_css_js');
}
```

**2)** Then later in the code I have this function, **to add theme support**. When you check the theme setup function, im just doing this:  rm_add_theme_support();. Is this the correct way to do it, or should I just copy everything from this fuction and paste it to theme_setup?

```
function rm_add_theme_support() {
add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');

// remove the default thumbnails
update_option('thumbnail_size_h', 0);
update_option('thumbnail_size_w', 0);
update_option('medium_size_h', 0);
update_option('medium_size_w', 0);
update_option('large_size_h', 0);
update_option('large_size_w', 0);

// set_post_thumbnail_size(200, 200, true);
add_image_size('rm-slide', 960, 500);
add_image_size('rm-service-image', 380, 9999);
add_image_size('rm-service-thumbnail', 80, 60, true);

add_theme_support('menus');

register_nav_menus(
    array(
        'main-nav' => 'Main menu'
    )
);
```

}

Thanks for all the help, hopefully this is not too much code.

Comment: What's your actual problem/question?

Comment: @ChipBennett Please read everything. Basically Im not sure about calling the rm_head_cleanup function in the after_setup_theme. And also about calling this: rm_add_theme_support();

Comment: Richard, that isn't a real question though. Questions are things that can have actual concrete answers. The only real answer anybody here will give you is that all that code is mostly unnecessary. You don't need to remove all those actions and filters and only hurt your site by doing such.

Comment: @Otto The question is, is this the right way or should it be done differently? I know its maybe not a specific question but I would like to understand how this works. So which ones I dont need? And which ones are hurting the site?

Answer (score 0):

What you should do:

- Read [Where to put my code: plugin or functions.php?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/73031/where-to-put-my-code-plugin-or-functions-php) and apply the lessons to your theme.

  Themes are for presentation only. Remove everything not related to presentation: do not touch `link` and `meta` elements in the header. That’s plugin territory.
- Remove redundant code. `add_theme_support('menus');` is not necessary, if you call `register_nav_menus()`. `update_option()` should not be called on every page load. Check the existing options first, and change it only if you have to.
- `add_theme_support('post-thumbnails');` is questionable, if you remove the thumbnail size. Why don’t you just change it to `80x60`? Then the thumbnails will still be available after a theme switch. This could be done with the other sizes too.

> should I just copy everything from this function and paste it to theme_setup?

No, keep separate tasks in separate functions or classes. Do not mix different tasks just to save some lines of code. It is easier to disable specific features with a plugin, when you follow the rule [Separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). `rm_add_theme_support()` does too much already, because menus are not related to image sizes.

Comment: Yeah I know about that but Im not going to create a plugin for everything, I have theme specific code there, and thats what there is functions.php file for. And I dont like to depend on a plugin to do all this stuff.

update_option is only run after_theme_setup or not?

Well Im also remove the other sizes, and then add my custom one also to keep the name consintency.

Okay so where should I put the register menus then? Im using a custom function to display the wp_nav_menu, could i put the register_menus there?

Comment: @RichardMišenčík You asked for a clean-up. Removing non-theme code is the first step. `after_theme_setup` is not a theme installation hook, it is called on every page load. You can change existing sizes, that’s better than removing the default sizes which might be used by plugins too. Register the menu in a separate function.

Comment: Yeah but wp_head cleanup function not code cleanup. Okay but when you check here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/after_setup_theme there is also add_theme_support, registering menus etc. in the after_theme_setup function. Im removing the default sizes because they are being created automatically from the images you upload, correct? I dont need these sizes, they are just waste of space and regarding plugins, Im not using any plugin so nothing will be used by plugins. So should I hook register_menus to add_action(init) like the head_cleanup()? Thanks.

Comment: @RichardMišenčík Please, please ignore code samples from Codex! They are very often questionable and show at best, how it _could_ be done, not how it _should_. You can change the default sizes and use those. I see no need for custom sizes. Menus can be registered on `wp_loaded`. See also [this example](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80271/73) (a little bit outdated).

Comment: can I also change the default names? because when using it with custom post types, its not very good to use thumbail_large or thumbnail_small when the name is not in the reference to the actual size. For menus i changed it like this: if(function_exists('register_nav_menus')) {
 register_nav_menus(
  array(...)
  )
 );
}. For the update_option i did something like: if (is_admin() && isset($_GET['activated']) && $pagenow == 'themes.php') { ... so i only delete and register the new thumbnail sizes on when the theme is activated.