# Adding Action Hooks In Parent Theme For Easier Child Theme Customization

Tags: theme-development, child-theme

I was wondering why isn't anyone (haven't be able to find one with it) adding custom hooks an the beginning and at the end of the theme's `function.php` for theme development.

The reason I'm asking this is while making a child theme, I had to overwrite some default setups like image sizes set in the parent theme's main `function.php` (no `!function_exists` to overwrite on). So anything I write in my child's `function.php`will be overwritten.

Aside from of course adding the `function_exists` wrapper, the solution I had in mind was just adding a `do_action()` at the beginning and at the end of the function.php. But is this a bad practice? If so, why?

I am unable to find any answers or anyone asking this anywhere.

Comment: Why at the beginning and the end?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Code in a `functions.php` (or any file loaded by that file) should not run automatically, eg. when the file is included. All code should be bound to hooks.
That means, you don’t need a special action in the parent theme. The child theme can turn off all parent theme callbacks with `remove_action()` and `remove_filter()`.

But you can make that easier for child theme authors by adding a custom action after you have registered the callbacks.

## Example

### Parent theme

```php
namespace ParentTheme;
// register callbacks
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', __NAMESPACE__ . '\setup_custom_background' );
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', __NAMESPACE__ . '\setup_custom_header' );
add_filter( 'body_class',        __NAMESPACE__ . '\enhance_body_class' );

// provide an entry point
do_action( 'parent_theme_loaded', __NAMESPACE__ );
```

### Child theme

```php
add_action( 'parent_theme_loaded', function( $namespace )
{
    remove_action( 'after_setup_theme', $namespace . '\setup_custom_header' );
});
```

See also this [similar example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/80271/73) for outdated PHP versions.

---

If your parent theme ignores the principle of [separation of concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) and mixes everything in just one or two setup functions, use a later priority and overwrite those calls:

### Parent theme

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'some_setup_function' ); // priority = 10
```

### Child theme

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'fix_theme_setup', 11 ); // priority = 11

function fix_theme_setup()
{
    remove_theme_support( 'post-formats' );
    // more changes here
}
```

Comment: Do you have a full functions.php example of your answer? It would help to understand the concept if we could see the whole thing.

Comment: @Daniel What do you miss?

Comment: Sorry, the whole concept is blur. How many custom actions do I add?

Comment: Just *one* after the list of callback registrations.

Comment: The problem is using remove_action() would remove a lot of other "init setup" stuff which I want. For example, wenty fourteen has a set_post_thumbnail_size( 672, 372, true ), along with many other setup functions. But because there isn't any function_exist wrapper or any hooks, I can't overwrite that in my child theme. Unless I copy everything in the setup and remove_action() the hook in the parent theme. What I'm suggesting is why not a simple hook which will let me overwrite one function?

Comment: @Bobby Then overwrite those settings. See my update.

Comment: alright, thanks a lot toscho! I am just making sure I'm not missing something. Gladly appreciate it.