# Do I actually need to link my theme's style.css in the theme files

Tags: theme-development, themes, css

So I am developing a wordpress theme using a series of LESS files for the CSS. These compile using codekit to a combined and minifed stylesheet that I use for the theme's styling.

I understand a wordpress theme must have a style.css which includes the info about the theme in its comments, but is it required to link this style.css in the header.php? Surely I can just have the theme info in it and nothing else and leave it untouched in the theme folder.
The stylesheet I actually use can just be called styles.css or main.css or something.

can anyone confirm this or give reasons why this might be a bad idea?

Comment: You should leave the `style.css` with theme infos at the root of your theme folder. That's it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I would say: you *should not* use the `style.css` for the actual production CSS.

The reason is simple: minification. You cannot minify the content of the file completely, because WordPress has to read it. In my themes, I use `style.css` just for the headers, and I add a comment, explaining where to find the real CSS, so other developers don’t have to search too long.

Example:

```
/*
Theme Name:    My theme name
Version:       2013.08.24
License:       MIT
Text Domain:   t5_theme
Domain Path:  /lang

You will find the real stylesheet in css/default.css.
*/
```

Comment: This is nice idea.

Comment: This is what I do as well, works like a charm.

Comment: Do you still need to enqueue style.css on the front end in order for WP to read the config?

Comment: @henrywright No, that was never necessary.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, Harry, that you do not need to actually call to or load the default `style.css` in your header file. Since I've been using SCSS in my themes, I've encountered this same issue, but had decided to maintain the link to `style.css` for the following reasons which may or may not be applicable to your situation:

- Default WP assumptions are that `style.css` exists and is in use, and I don't want to thwart that assumption with respect to plugins. I don't know if/when this would be an issue and would be interested to hear others' experiences and advice on this point.
- If my actual in-use stylesheet is in a folder, it prevents users from being able to edit the site's CSS. Keeping `style.css` active and available gives my users a way to still be able to make CSS changes from the WP admin.
- Related, while working on the staging site with other partners, if they don't also use SCSS, they can make changes to `style.css` without affecting my ability to continue to use my SCSS files.

Again, these points may not be applicable to your situation but have informed my decision to keep the default `style.css` linked, even if it's mostly blank except for the required theme info.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, WordPress uses the theme's `style.css` as a "config" document.

You are also correct, as far as I can tell, that you don't have to actually load `style.css` on the front end in order to have it serve its "config" purposes.

What you are doing should be fine. I am pretty sure I have seen other themes do something similar but I can't swear to it. The only issue I can see would be if some plugin erroneously assumes that `style.css` is the (only) stylesheet in the theme.

Answer (score 1):

You could also add this to your `config.rb` (if you're using Compass) and CodeKit will automatically copy your minified stylesheet to `style.css` in the theme root.

```
require 'fileutils'
on_stylesheet_saved do |file|
  if File.exists?(file) && File.basename(file) == "style.css"
    puts "Moving: #{file}"
    FileUtils.mv(file, File.dirname(file) + "/../" + File.basename(file))
  end
end
```

I use this with every WordPress theme I develop and it works like a charm.

Make sure that the comment in your `style.scss` file starts with the `!` after the opening comment or else it will be removed in the minification:

```
/*!
  Theme Name: Your Theme
```

Source: [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/compass-compiling-and-wordpress-themes/)

Comment: That trick with adding exclamation point after beginning /* did the trick for me. Means I can keep processing the less file -> css and still keep the format that WordPress expects to read the theme details. Easiest trick I have seen in a long time (one character the right place!) :-)