# Move my theme style.css into a folder

Tags: theme-development, directory, css

I was wondering if its possible to have my theme `style.css` in a `css` folder rather than in the root? I assume that the Theme Metadata has to be in the theme root, but could the actual styles be moved? Is this a piece of meta data I would add to the theme meta?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can just register another stylesheet instead of `style.css`:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_theme_css' );

function enqueue_theme_css()
{
    wp_enqueue_style(
        'default',
        get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/default.css'
    );
}
```

This is, in [my opinion](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/111228/73), better than using `style.css`.

Comment: Your link is useful. THis leads me to wonder what the difference between `get_template_directory_uri` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri`. Is it just the filters that are applied? @toscho

Comment: @JamieWright `template` refers to the parent theme if there is one. `stylesheet` is the currently used theme. If you don’t write a child theme, use the `template` functions.

Comment: It's worth noting that style.css has to be in the root directory of the theme in order to register the theme with WordPress (to show up on Appearance > Themes). However, you don't have to use it to actually load styles.

Comment: And where do you add said function?

Comment: @user3411192 In the `functions.php`.

Comment: @fuxia This is a great tip! I tried it and I got a white screen though? Any thoughts on why that might be?

Comment: @DavidA.French Probably a syntax error. Check your code with syntax highlighting on.

Comment: Since the code was basically the same as what I had used to customize my login page, I basically just used that and changed it to the proper wp_enqueue etc like yours and it worked! don't know what was the issue though.

Answer (score 0):

Originally I said

> You could make your child theme stylesheet import another stylesheet
>
> @import url("subdirectory/file.css");*

But this was incorrect as this is no longer the preferred way to reference a style sheet.

Now, I have discovered a plugin that makes child's play of creating a child theme (please excuse the pun) https://wordpress.org/plugins/child-theme-configurator/

You could probably use this plugin to enqueue your other stylesheet. Might be worth having a look at the instructions to see if this is practical.

Hope this helps.

Comment: `@import` is slow, because the browser has to parse the first stylesheet in order to obtain the URL. And please do not use hard-coded paths. `wp_content` as well as the WordPress installation directory can be any name, so this is not portable code.

Comment: For more information on Child Themes see https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes