# Change directory of javascript files

Tags: directory, footer, scripts

I'd like to move all my assets (CSS, JS, Images, Fonts) in an asset folder in my theme.

I did it very well for the fonts and images. For the CSS, I just kept the style.css with the style meta information in it (as advised [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111505/133812)).

But I'm using the great underscores.me starter theme for Wordpress and I have in my theme a JS folder containing customizer, navigation.js and skip-link-focus-fix.js

All these scripts are included in my footer via the wp_footer() function. So, if I move these scripts to my /assets/js/ folder, I have three missing files called in the footer.

Is there a way to (1) not load these scripts or (2) change the directory and tell the wp_footer to call /assets/js and not /js/ ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to your themes `functions.php` and find line 122. You will find navigation.js function.

```
get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/navigation.js
```

and change it to

```
get_template_directory_uri() . 'assets/js/navigation.js
```

do it again for `skip-link-focus-fix.js` code located on line 124.

For customizer go and find `customizer.php` in 'inc' folder. Go line 53 and change `js/customizer.js` code to `assets/js/customizer.js`

Don't forget to move your files :)

Comment: Indeed. I don't know why I didn't check this file! Thank you for your help @Serkan By the way, are these scripts necessary?

Comment: You are welcome. Customizer anda navigation possibly needed. About other one i am not sure.

Answer (score 0):

These scripts are enqueued in functions.php using function wp_enqueue_script(). So open your functions.php file, search for these scripts then remove the call so as not to load them, or change the path to your new directory.