# Caching and Versioning for rtl.css

Tags: theme-development, localization, wp-head, cache

I am using `filemtime()` to add a version number for different **.css** and **.js** files in a custom WordPress theme.

I used the [accepted answer described here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/40667/how-do-you-avoid-caching-during-development) as a guideline; however, I use the `wp_retister_style()` and `wp_register_script()` functions to register my **.css** and **.js** files respectively, and evetually load them via `wp_enqueue_style()` and `wp_enqueue_script()`. As an example, I am registering **sigle.css** file this way:

```
wp_register_style('xyz_single', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/single.css', false, filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/single.css'));
```

The fourth parameter in the function above will add **?ver=nnnnnnnn** to the stylesheet. The final output will be something like **single.css?ver=nnnnnnnn**, where **nnnnnnnn** is a number representing the timestamp of the modified file in order to esure reloading it when I modify the theme so caching issues are taken care off.

Now, to my question.

In my custome theme, I use **rtl.css**, which is loaded automatically for me when `wp_head()` is called. So how do I append **rtl.css** to include a version number?

---

### More information

In **header.php**, I am loading **style.css** as follows:

```
<link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_uri() . '?ver=' . filemtime(get_stylesheet_directory() . '/style.css'); ?>" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I am loading all other stylesheets using `wp_register_style()` as described above, followed by `wp_enqueue_style()`. Here is an example:

```
wp_register_style('xyz_single', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/single.css', false, filemtime(get_template_directory() . '/css/single.css'));

wp_enqueue_style('xyz-single');
```

However, **rtl.css** is automatically loaded when I call `wp_head()` in **header.php**. Please [read this great article](http://www.fklein.info/rtl-styles-loaded/) on how `wp_head()` loads **rtl.css**; and hence my question, *how can I add a version number to **rtl.css** if it is called automatically?*

Comment: how is it being loaded? please edit the question and explain. Please also explain the context, that prevents you from handling rtl.css the same way you handle style.css

Comment: @MarkKaplun - Thanks, I updated the question. I hope this explains it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are loading the **rtl.css** using the WordPress automatic way, that is, having a **rtl.css** in the theme folder will be loaded by WordPress automatically if it presents and direction of current language ir rtl (you should add this information to the question, it has been difficult to figure it out how you are loading the file). This process defines `locale_stylesheet_uri` that you can use to modify the locale stylesheet URL, so you can add the version parameter to it:

```
add_filter( 'locale_stylesheet_uri', function ($localized_stylesheet_uri) {
    $time_ver = filemtime( get_stylesheet_directory() . '/rtl.css' );
    return add_query_arg( array('ver' => $time_ver), $localized_stylesheet_uri );
});
```

If you need also handle dependencies you will have to load **rlt.css** file with `wp_enqueue_style` just like any other css file. No way of handling dependencies with the "auto" way.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the article you have pointed to, it seems like there are two simple options

1. prevent the automatic inclusion by removing the actions that makes it to be added,

`remove_action( 'wp_head', 'locale_stylesheet' );`

and enqueue it with your own code, something like

```
global $$wp_locale; 

$stylesheet_dir_uri = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
$dir = get_stylesheet_directory();
$locale = get_locale();


if ( !empty($wp_locale->text_direction) && file_exists("$dir/{$wp_locale->text_direction}.css") )
        enqueue "$stylesheet_dir_uri/{$wp_locale->text_direction}.css";
```

2. use the `'locale_stylesheet_uri'` filter, and add whatever suffix you prefer to the url, or just return `''` and enqueue it by yourself like in #1